# use min-height % and px on the same div

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to say

```
min-height: 500px;
min-height: 100%;
```

why I'm willing to use this?

The div needs to be 100% or longer so it can overflow.
only when the screen is smaller than 500px in height it needs to be 500px so it will align good with the other elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a media query:

```
@media screen and (max-height:500px) {
    .selector { min-height: 500px; }
}
```

Comment: yes that i was looking for, stupid me for not thinking about it!

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery to set this behavior.

In case you don't want to add Jquery library, you can strive to do it with Vanilla Javascript. By the way, performance is better without using Jquery.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There should be an explanation of how to solve the problem. A reference to jQuery or Vanilla JavaScript is not enough.

Comment: Why jQuery when CSS3 can do it with Media Queries?

Comment: Well, the OP wanted a CSS3 solution, easier implemented.

Comment: Sorry about that.
Here is a more complete answer:

You can try this:
https://gist.github.com/mauryaratan/4283646

There is an example of how to do it.

Regards,